# How to fix "App not installed" - Xamarin app distribution

Tags: android, xamarin, apk

I used Microsoft's "Preparing an Application for Release" and "Signing the Android Application Package" tutorials in order to run an APK of an app I built on my Samsung Galaxy S8 phone.
When I try to run the APK, I am getting a message "Do you want to install an update to this existing application?...", and when tap "install", it shows an "installing" screen, and after couple of seconds I am getting a message "App not installed".
I have done these steps couple of times, each time I got the same result.

Did it happen to anyone?
Is there a way to know for 100% what causes this problem? There is not error code and it leaves me hanging.

Comment: remove the previous installed version & then install your latest app. The problem might be with configuration, the already installed build is debug build & u installing Release build over it, which isnt allowed

Comment: @Blu, I removed previous versions and then installed my latest app, unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: try restarting the device, if problem still persist, there might be problem in creating build, try making another new build.

Comment: @Blu I restarted phone, didn't help. Created new Helloworld project, and it worked. What do you recomment doint with the old (and real) project that does not work? Copy it to a new project?

Comment: Check adb logcat to see what goes wrong when installing your app

Comment: @Cheesebaron  Can you please help me figuring out how to use adb logcat? where to write it exactly? "Installing app" is on my phone, and I assume you mean to do this on my PC.

Comment: Connect your phone to your computer. In a terminal navigate to the platform-tools folder in the Android SDK and run `adb logcat` or you can use Visual Studio to show logcat for you

Comment: @Cheesebaron Thank you, I was able to get the log after trying to install the app. What am I supposed to find? There are many lines of code there, and the ones with the app package name do not give that much information.

Comment: Find the error in the log obviously. There will be one with a reason as to why it didn't install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to thank @Blu and @Cheesebaron for their guidance.

OK, so after trying to understand where my error was (a lot of ctrl+f's), I had:
"failure copying native libraries error **code=-113**".
This means I had to my app.Android in Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Android Options -> Advanced -> unchecked all except the last one, then unchecked it, and it checked right back what was needed for it to work.
Then it didn't work AGAIN.
So I looked up again in logcat (after trying to install again, so that I will see the new error), and I found this:
"**signatures do not match** previously installed version; ignoring!".
I went to Settings -> Apps -> searched my app by its name -> Uninstalled.
Then I tried installing again, and it worked!

BTW, for the sake of other people - How to use logcat? (generally! you may experience some issues, google it and you'll do fine):

1. Connect your phone to your computer.
2. go into: c:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
3. type "adb logcat".

Comment: glad that you have fixed it on your own :)